# How to resolve Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js, go-ethereum

I am trying to call a solidity function and am getting an error. This is how I create my contract:

```
var EthProjContract = web3.eth.contract(my abi);
var EthProj = EthProjContract.at('0xcce478FDeF9F1DF933e31B1eeA48561e0095628A');
```

I am calling my function like this:

```
EthProj.setMessage.sendTransaction(shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value), {from: document.getElementById("add").value})
```

and get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

If you are wondering what shoco.compress is, it compressed my strings into uint8arrays. For example,

`shoco.compress("Hello")` returns `Uint8Array(3) [72, 193, 77]`

If I have `Hello` in my `MessageBox` box and call

```
EthProj.setMessage.sendTransaction(shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value), {from: document.getElementById("add").value})
```

I get the error. But, when I call

```
EthProj.setMessage.sendTransaction([72, 193, 77], {from: document.getElementById("add").value})
```

it works perfectly. This means it can't be anything with getting my text. So what could it be? All I could think that it could possibly be is that `Uint8Array(3)` being in there could be messing it up. If so, how could I fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I formatted the code in the post wrong, I edited it to be correct. I think I am on to something on how to fix it though. When I do this: `var message = [0, 0, 0];
            message[0] = shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value)[0];
            message[1] = shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value)[1];
            message[2] = shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value)[2];` And `sendTransaction` using message as my argument, it works. Only if I can make it have something like a variable length.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my error.
Here is how I did it.

```
 var message = [0, 0, 0];
        for(var i = 0; i < shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value).length; i++) {
            message.length = shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value).length;
            message[i] = shoco.compress(document.getElementById("MessageBox").value)[i];
        }
```

I discovered that it was not working because it said `uint8array` in the return of `shoco.compress`. I fixed this by creating a new array and setting that array to be equal to my `shoco.compress`, getting rid of the `uint8array`.